# How to read the annotations defined on return type of a Method programmatically

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How can we read the annotations defined on return type of a Method programmatically?

I tried looking for methods in java.lang.reflect.Method but I could only find the ways to read the class type of the return value or read the generic information.Is there a method to read the annotations as well?

**Consider this method definition:-**

```
public class ABC {
      public static @MyAnnotation @AnotherAnnotation String main(String args[]) {

       return null;        
      }
```

**So my question is :- Can we read the annotations defined in the return type String??**

The annotations are as follows:-

MyAnnotation.java

```
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    public String[] author() default {"Its me","Its me"};



}
```

AnotherAnnotation.java

```
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AnotherAnnotation {

}
```

Comment: The annotation is set on the method itself, not on the return type.

Comment: @JBNizet This compiles fine for me.So how can we read this annotation?

Comment: By getting the annotations from the Method object representing this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused by the placement of the annotation:

```
public static @MyAnnotation @AnotherAnnotation String main(String args[])
```

These two annotations are not annotating the return type of the method. They're annotating the method itself. The above is equivalent to

```
@MyAnnotation 
@AnotherAnnotation 
public static String main(String args[])
```

or even to

```
public @MyAnnotation @AnotherAnnotation static String main(String args[])
```

You get them from the `Method` object, using [`getAnnotations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#getAnnotations%28%29) or [`getDeclaredAnnotations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations%28%29).

Comment: Thanks JB.This seems to explain why we can annotate even void return types.It would have been helpful if compiler would have stopped us from using the annotation in that place itself and suggested it to use on method itself.